# Making sprites move in oppsite direction of vector

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a sprite that moves from the bottom left of the screen to the top right. What I want to know is how would i make it turn around and go in the opposite direction, and continue this loop.

I tried negating  the direction of the vector but that doesnt work.

This what i have right now:

```
public void create() {
    // Game Initialization  
    v = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 0); 
    v.nor();
    v.scl(100);

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(); 
    bug = new Sprite(new Texture("EnemyBug.png"));
    bug.setSize(50, 85);
    bug.setOrigin(0,0);//Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5);
    bug.setPosition(1,1);//Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 50, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 50);
    bug.rotate(v.angle());

    rotDeg = 5;
}

@Override
public void render() {
    // Game Loop

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.begin();        

    if(bug.getX() >= (int)(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 100) && bug.getY() >= (int)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 100)){
        turn = !turn;
    }
    else if(bug.getX() <= 50 && bug.getY() <= 50){
        turn = !turn;
    }


    if(!turn){          
        bug.translate(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    }
    else{
        bug.translate(-(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()), -(v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()));
    }

    bug.translate(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    bug.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are translating the sprite twice per frame:

```
if(!turn){          
        bug.translate(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    }
    else{
        bug.translate(-(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()), -(v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()));
    }

    //REMOVE THIS LINE
    bug.translate(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

That extra line may be causing your problem, nullifying your negative translation and doubling the positive one.

Comment: it is an if statement, it would only do one of them per frame. the line you are telling me to remove makes the sprite go to the top right corner, the one with the negative is supposed to make it go from the top right to the bottom left.

Comment: The translate on the if will make it go on the positive direction. The other translate on the else will make it go negative. The extra one will always be executed doubling the positive and nullifying the negative.

Comment: so how would i implement it? do i remove the whole if/else statement?

Comment: oh ok, thanks i didnt know i had one translate function outside the if statement. Btw how would I make it rotate in the opposite direction smoothly. When I do  `bug.rotate(180)` it makes a sudden turn.

Comment: You'll have to rotate a bit every frame. The same way you translate a bit every frame. Create an angularVelocity variable and do something like `bug.rotate(angularVelocity * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());`